# How to send an email through an outlook.com alias email address on iOS?

Tags: ios, email, alias, hotmail

**Outlook.com** (past Live Mail / Hotmail) allows creation of email aliases associated to one main account, which is very convenient.

Using **Exchange ActiveSync** with an iOS device works really well on all tasks, but one can't send/reply emails using one of those aliases.

Is there any productive way of using these outlook.com aliases on an iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any actual answer for my question, but instead found a very good alternative.

Basically **@icloud.com** accounts also allow the creation of aliases that can be used in all iOS Mail apps, with one particular advantage: the alias allows changing the name of the recipient as well, something **@outlook.com** account aliases does not allow.

You can create **@icloud.com** aliases using the web interface options.